# Confusion about the definition of Work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

I am trying to make sense of the meaning of the definition of work. The original definition of work was also known as "the weight lifted through a height." I was hoping that our mathematical definition of work would correspond to this notion in a well-defined way but it seems like it doesn't.

According to our mathematical definition of work, if I "lift the weight through a height" at two different constant accelerations, say, I get two different values for the amount of work I have done.

Why do we make the definition like this? Why don't we make the definition such that the work done by "lifting a weight through a height" doesn't depend on the velocity/acceleration with which it is lifted. It seems the definition was originally intended for this and it got changed along the way somewhere.

Consider a path $x(t): x(0) = 0, x'(0) = 0$ taking values on the real line and $x''(t) = a = F$. Then if $T_a = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}$ then $x(T_a) = 1$. Also $W = \int_0^{T_a} F \cdot x'(t) dt = \int_0^{T_a} a \cdot at dt = a$.

Comment: What you're saying isn't true. Lifting a fixed mass over a fixed distance always needs the same work, regardless of how fast you do it. But for differing accelerations, you have to consider that the final velocity, and hence kinetic energy, of the mass may be different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)

Comment: What mathematical definition of work were you given that doesn't give the same result as "weight lifted through height"?

Comment: Consider the example I just gave in the question.

Comment: @The Photon I am using the line integral definition. See the example above. Does it not make sense?

Comment: Does anyone here understand this? When you normally do some computation in your physics books you see for example some force $F$ and some path $x$. You are interpreting my question as "why does the work change when we reparametrize the curve $x$. Of course it does not change since the line integral is invariant under change of parametrization but this is NOT what I am asking. I am changing the parametrization by changing the FORCE since this is what happens when I lift a weight in real life.

Comment: Aha.  I don't know where you got your definition, but it is severely misleading.  Note this:  if you start with your object at rest on earth, then accelerate it with your hand quickly and stop it at some height $h$, your hand must first apply a "positive" force to speed it up, then a "negative" force to bring it to rest.  The net work done by your hand is zero.  The work done by the force of gravity is not zero, and is equal to $mgh$.  See the link @brucesmitherson gives.

Comment: I think what you say is not correct since if the object had zero kinetic energy to begin with and had zero kinetic energy after I stopped it and the net work done by my hand is zero and the net work done by gravity is non zero then the total net work done is non zero but this is not correct since the kinetic energy has not changed.

Comment: @Joe - It's true that, in your example, kinetic energy has not changed. But potential energy has, and that is where the work went. The definition you quoted tacitly assumes that the starting and final (vertical) velocities are the same, usually zero for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions and units (setting $m=1$ and choosing the length $l$ of the path also $1$) obscure the connection to the "lift" definition, but in fact they coincide for the given situation.

The formula you derived for the work done against a constant force is
$ W = a $, which should really read

$$ W = m\cdot a\cdot l$$

If the force on the body is due to gravity and height above ground doesn't change too much, gravitational acceleration is basically constant $a=g$ giving back the familiar formula $mgh$ with $h$ identified with $l$.

Note that "lift the weight through a height" is only a sensible definition for work done against gravity if the force can be assumed to be constant. It is a limiting case of the general expression of work as the line integral of a force.

Also be aware that work cannot only be done against gravity, but also e.g an electric field. Defining work through lifting is somewhat nonsensical, less one defines "lifting" as "moving against a force", which brings us back to the integral formulation.